# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx \ne \int_0^1\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx^2}~\forall~n=1,2,\cdots$ and $x$ real, show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx \ne  \int_0^1\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) dx$$

**Attempt:**

By the $Mn$ Test, it comes out that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

We also know that if $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of functions and if $f$ is the limiting function, then :

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx =  \int_0^1\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) dx$$

However, this is just a sufficient condition and a non uniformly convergent sequence of functions may also exhibit the same properties.

In such a case, how do we prove the above relation in this and other problems? Is  direct integration the only method to follow in such problems?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: Yes, it's fairly easy to integrate $f_n$ (hint: $(e^{-nx^2})'=-2nxe^{-nx^2}$)

Comment: Thank you. Though, I feel that's a bit strange because this problem arises in the chapter on Sequence of functions where uniform convergence is asked for.

Comment: Just calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ an you will know why those expressions are not the same.

Comment: @Shakespeare and @Gregor~ Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,
$$\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=n\int_0^1 xe^{-nx^2}dx=n\left[-\frac{1}{2n}e^{-nx^2}\right]_0^1=n\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n}e^{-n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-n}$$
and thus 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Secondly,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }nxe^{-nx^2}=0$$
and thus 
$$\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)dx=0.$$

We conclude that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\neq \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)dx.$$

Comment: Thank you. So, no concept involved using the properties of uniformily convergent function sequences right